# Magento 2 : how to get category name in my custom product grid

Tags: magento2, admin, category, grid, custom-admin-grid

My prepare collection code :

```
 protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $store = $this->_getStore();
        $collection = $this->productFactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(
            'sku'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'name'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'attribute_set_id'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'type_id'
        )->setStore(
            $store
        );

        if ($this->moduleManager->isEnabled('Magento_CatalogInventory')) {
            $collection->joinField(
                'qty',
                'cataloginventory_stock_item',
                'qty',
                'product_id=entity_id',
                '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                'left'
            );
        }
        if ($store->getId()) {
            $collection->setStoreId($store->getId());
            $collection->addStoreFilter($store);
            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'name',
                'catalog_product/name',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'inner',
                Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID
            );

            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'status',
                'catalog_product/status',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'inner',
                $store->getId()
            );
            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'visibility',
                'catalog_product/visibility',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'inner',
                $store->getId()
            );

            $collection->joinAttribute('price', 'catalog_product/price', 'entity_id', null, 'left', $store->getId());


        } else {
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect('price');
            $collection->joinAttribute('status', 'catalog_product/status', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
            $collection->joinAttribute('visibility', 'catalog_product/visibility', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
        }
        $this->setCollection($collection);

        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn(
            'in_products',
            [
                'type' => 'checkbox',
                'html_name' => 'products_id',
                'required' => true,
                'values' => $this->_getSelectedProducts(),
                'align' => 'center',
                'index' => 'entity_id',
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'entity_id',
            [
                'header' => __('ID'),
                'width' => '50px',
                'index' => 'entity_id',
                'type' => 'number',
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'name',
            [
                'header' => __('Name'),
                'index' => 'name',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-type',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-type',
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'sku',
            [
                'header' => __('SKU'),
                'index' => 'sku',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-sku',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-sku',
            ]
        );
        $store = $this->_getStore();
        $this->addColumn(
            'price',
            [
                'header' => __('Price'),
                'type' => 'price',
                'currency_code' => $store->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(),
                'index' => 'price',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-price',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-price',
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'position',
            [
                'header' => __('Position'),
                'name' => 'position',
                'width' => 60,
                'type' => 'number',
                'validate_class' => 'validate-number',
                'index' => 'position',
                'editable' => true,
                'edit_only' => true,
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'brand',
            [
                'header' => __('Brand'),
                'type' => 'options',
                'index' => 'brand',
                'name' => 'brand',
                'options' => $this->getBrandsOptionArray(),
                'header_css_class' => 'col-brand',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-brand',
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn('category_name',
            array(
                'header' => 'Category Name',
                'type' => 'options',
                'align' => 'left',
                'index' => 'category_name'
            )
        );

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First add the column Category in product grid.
You have inserted the Category column but expand the product_listing.xml file as below in your module.

`1. Add product_listing.xml`
***app\code\YourVendor\YourModule\view\adminhtml\ui_component\product_listing.xml***

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="product_columns" class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <column name="category_id" class="YourVendor\YourModule\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Category">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">YourVendor\YourModule\Model\Category\Categorylist</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category Name</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">99</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

`2. Add Categorylist.php`
**app\code\YourVendor\YourModule\Model\Category\Categorylist.php**

```
namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Model\Category;
 
class CategoryList implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->_categoryCollectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
 
    }
    public function toOptionArray($addEmpty = true)
    {
 
         $collection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');
        $options = [];
        if ($addEmpty) {
            $options[] = ['label' => __('-- Please Select a Category --'), 'value' => ''];
        }
        foreach ($collection as $category) {
            $options[] = ['label' => $category->getName(), 'value' => $category->getId()];
        }
        return $options;
    }
}
```

`3. Add Category.php` and override the prepareDataSource Method. Get category values to the in prepareDataSource like below
**app\code\YourVendor\YourModule\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Category.php**

```
namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;
 
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
 
class Category extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column
{
 
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $productId = $item['entity_id'];
 
                $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
                $cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
                $categories = array();
                if (count($cats)) {
                    foreach ($cats as $cat) {
                        $category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($cat);
                        $categories[] = $category->getName();
                    }
                }
                $item[$fieldName] = implode(',', $categories);
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

Create app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\adminhtml\ui_component\product_listing.xml

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<columns name="product_columns" class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
    <column name="category_id" class="Vendor\Extension\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Category">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Extension\Model\Category\Categorylist</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Categories</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">75</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created At</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="updated_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Updated At</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
</columns>
```

Create app\code\Vendor\Extension\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Ui\DataProvider\Product;
class ProductDataProvider extends \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider
{
    public function addFilter(\Magento\Framework\Api\Filter $filter)
    {
        if ($filter->getField() == 'category_id') {
            $this->getCollection()->addCategoriesFilter(array('in' => $filter->getValue()));
        } elseif (isset($this->addFilterStrategies[$filter->getField()])) {
            $this->addFilterStrategies[$filter->getField()]
                ->addFilter(
                    $this->getCollection(),
                    $filter->getField(),
                    [$filter->getConditionType() => $filter->getValue()]
                );
        } else {
            parent::addFilter($filter);
        }
    }
}
```

Create app\code\Vendor\Extension\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Category.php

```
<?php 
namespace Vendor\Extension\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;
 
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
 
class Category extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column
{
 
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $productId = $item['entity_id'];
 
                $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
                $cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
                $categories = array();
                if (count($cats)) {
                    foreach ($cats as $cat) {
                        $category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($cat);
                        $categories[] = $category->getName();
                    }
                }
                $item[$fieldName] = implode(',', $categories);
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Create app\code\Vendor\Extension\Model\Category\Categorylist.php

```
<?php 
namespace Vendor\Extension\Model\Category;
 
class CategoryList implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->_categoryCollectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
 
    }
    public function toOptionArray($addEmpty = true)
    {
 
         $collection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');//->addRootLevelFilter()->load();
        $options = [];
        if ($addEmpty) {
            $options[] = ['label' => __('-- Please Select a Category --'), 'value' => ''];
        }
        foreach ($collection as $category) {
            $options[] = ['label' => $category->getName(), 'value' => $category->getId()];
        }
        return $options;
    }
}
```

Create app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider" type="Vendor\Extension\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider" />
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This It will work For Your Block Grid

**Replace the category column with the below code**

```
$this->addColumn(
            'category',
            [
                'header' => __('Category'),
                'index' => 'category',
                'sortable' => false,
                'type' => 'options',
                'align' => 'left',
                'options' => $this->_objectManager->create(\Vendor\Module\Model\Source\Category::class)
                    ->getAllOptions() ,
                'renderer' => \Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Renderer\Category::class,
                'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, 'filterCategory'),
            ]
        );
```

**Now add the Filter callback condition in the same file as function**

```
public function filterCategory($collection, $column)
    {
        $value = $column->getFilter()->getValue();
        $_category = $this->_objectManager->create(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::class)->load($value);
        $collection->addCategoryFilter($_category);
        return $collection;
    }
```

**Now Option File : Vendor\Module\Model\Source\Category.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Source;

use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory;

class Category implements OptionSourceInterface
{
    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    public $category;

    public $storeManager;

    public $allowedLevels = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

    /**
     * Category constructor.
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->category = $collectionFactory;
    }

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $categories = $this->category->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('level')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('level', ['in', $this->allowedLevels])
            ->setStore($this->storeManager->getStore());
        $options = [
            [
                'label' => '',
                'value' => '',
            ]
        ];

        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category */
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $space = str_repeat('&nbsp;', $category->getLevel() * 3);
            $option['label'] = $space . $category->getName() . " [{$category->getEntityId()}]";
            $option['value'] = $category->getEntityId();
            $options[] = $option;
        }
        return $options;
    }

    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        return $this->getOptionArray();
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getOptionArray()
    {
        $options = [];
        foreach ($this->toOptionArray() as $option) {
            $options[$option['value']] = (string)$option['label'];
        }
        return $options;
    }
}
```

**Renderer File : Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Renderer\Category.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Renderer;

class Category extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer
{
    public $categoryFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);

        $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
    }

    public function render(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row)
    {
        $categoryIds = $row->getCategoryIds();
        $categories = $this->categoryFactory->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => $categoryIds]);
        $html = [];
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $html[] = $category->getName();
        }

        $html = implode(',<br/>', $html);
        return $html;
    }
}
```

After that Cache Flush